# Why itemSort is not triggered when I hover a dataset point in Chart.js?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I can't figure out why my console.log isn't triggered in the Chart.js tooltip itemSort function. Do I miss something ?

```
plugins: {
      legend: {
        display: false,
      },
      tooltip: {
        backgroundColor: "transparent",
        titleColor: "black",
        titleAlign: "center",
        bodyColor: "black",
        bodyAlign: "center",
        displayColors: false,
        callbacks: {
          label: (element) => element.raw,
        },
        itemSort: (elements) => {
          console.log("elements", elements);
          return elements;
        },
      },
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because by default the interaction mode is `'point'` so it only shows a single value and thus can not be sorted. So chart.js does not call the method. If you make it another interaction mode like `'index'` where it shows the tooltip for all datapoints at that data index it is getting called:

```js
const options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderWidth: 1
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        borderWidth: 1
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      tooltip: {
        mode: 'index',
        itemSort: (e, x) => {
          console.log(e.raw, x.raw) // Dont log entire objects since stack does not like that
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

const ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.7.0/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

**Edit:**
From your comment on deleted answer if you want to change the order of the label and the value you should use the `label` callback instead of using the sort function

```js
const options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderWidth: 1
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        borderWidth: 1
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      tooltip: {
        callbacks: {
          label: (e) => (`${e.formattedValue}, ${e.label}`)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

const ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.7.0/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: This is insane !! I can't get it work like you do :(

Comment: ...and remove the default label with the `filter` props ?

Comment: Are you sure you are running version 3 of the lib? And no if you don't want to show the default label you should not return it in the label callback, only return what you want to show

Comment: Yes, i'm sure. I verified, `"chart.js": "^3.7.0"`...

Comment: This is what I had to do :
```label: () => {},
title: (e) => `${e[0].formattedValue}, ${e[0].label}`
```

Comment: And last but not least, TYSH dude, you were very helpfull. Hope you're doing well <3 !